# Does the 4 GB Xbox 360 have enough space for 5 gamer profiles and saved games?

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

I have just recently decided to buy my younger brothers an xbox 360 slim for their birthday. I would like to save as much money as possible so I am looking to get them the 4GB system. I understand there is 246GB difference in the systems, but should I really worry about this if all they are doing is saving gamer profiles on the console and saving games? They will not be adding it to xbox live so there is no need to save downloaded data or anything else from live. Will 4GB be sufficient enough for 5 gamer profiles and saved content?

Comment: Sorry about my close vote, I voted after reading the title.  Shopping recommendations are off-topic, but asking about what will fit on the drive seems reasonable.  I've edited the title to reflect the question body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that should have more than enough space for that. I've had my Xbox 360 for close to two and a half years, and after playing 100 or so games my profile takes up about 10MB. As for save games, I'm not sure how much space mine are taking but most save games are less than 1MB so there should be plenty of room for them as well.

If you do need more room and don't want to spring for the 250GB hard drive (now or later - it is cheaper to buy it with the console, though) you can always use USB drives for storage. The Xbox 360 supports drives up to 16GB.

Note that the vast majority of games don't require a hard drive, but some do. The only ones I'm aware of off hand are Halo 3, Halo 3 ODST, and Halo Reach. In this case, you can play the game but you can't play the campaign or Firefight in co-op mode (at least online - not sure if the same restriction exists for local co-op).

Comment: My gamerscore is 55,555, and my gamer profile is only 30 MB, so I agree with you about profiles. The vast majority of my saved games are under 1 MB; the biggest ones are games like Madden where a lot of info is stored, but even with a Superstar save and a Franchise save and roster update, that's still only about 13 MB. Without Marketplace purchases, I agree that the 4 GB drive will be fine for now.

Comment: I've had a Slim for several years, and I think you'd never have a problem if you don't plan to use Live, as you mention.  Also @Adeese I think your information about the Halo games is incorrect/misleading.  The Slim still has a disk, just a small one.  I don't think there would be any issue playing all of these games. Bungie recommends loading some of them to disk, but it is not required.  Now, Halo 4 on the other hand requires a disk load for online multiplayer - but then, with no Live that is not a problem.

Comment: @EBongo Not sure if this is still the case or not, but at least when Halo Reach shipped it required a hard drive for co-op: http://joystiq.com/2010/09/15/halo-reach-co-op-requires-hard-drive-4gb-xbox-360-slims-have-t/ . The article indicates MS might be working on a fix, but I don't know if that ever happened or not.

Answer (score 2):

It has enough for a saved games, but a concern would be that it restricts you ability to download updates and DLC for games, which can interfere with your ability to play online. For example, Burnout Paradise's free updates along would use up 1/3 of your space. And while Burnout is an outlier in file size, it's still possible for free updates of an average number of games to fill that drive. On my 360, which I've had for a couple of years now, I have 9GB used up between DLC, updates, saved games and three albums.

Answer (score 0):

I would think yes becuase my Xbox only uses at least 1 mb to save a game and I've played at least 6 games and its down to 3 gb but if you get a hard drive that will be better for space and  saving your account.sorry for my long sentences and using no periods I'm not from the America's I'm from Japan.